# Definition of First and Follow sets of the right-hand sides of production

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

I am learning about LL(1) grammars. I have a task of checking if grammar is LL(1) and if not, I then need to find the rules, which prevent it from being LL(1). I came across this link [https://www.csd.uwo.ca/~mmorenom/CS447/Lectures/Syntax.html/node14.html](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Emmorenom/CS447/Lectures/Syntax.html/node14.html) which has a theorem which can be used as a criteria for deciding if grammar is LL(1) or not. It says that for any rule `A -> alpha | beta`  some equalities, considering FIRST and FOLLOW sets need to be true. Therefore, I need to find FIRST and FOLLOW sets of these right-hand sides of production.

Let's say, I have following rules  `A -> a b B S | eps`. How do I calculate FIRST and FOLLOW of `a b B S`? As far as I understand by definition these sets are defined only for 1 non-terminal symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind the FIRST function is that it returns the set of terminals which could possibly start the expansion of its argument. It's usual to also add the special object ε (which is a way of writing an empty sequence of symbols) if ε is a possible expansion.

So if *a* is a terminal, FIRST(*a*) is just { a }. And if *A* is a non-terminal, FIRST(*A*) is the set of non-terminals which could possibly appear at the beginning of a derivation of *A*. Finally, FIRST(ε) must be { ε }, according to the convention described above.

Now suppose α is a (possibly empty) sequence of grammar symbols:

- If α is empty (that is, it's ε), FIRST(α) is { ε }
- If the first symbol in α is the terminal *a*, FIRST(α) is { a }.
- If the first symbol in α is the non-terminal *A*, there are two possibilities. Let TAIL(α) be the rest of α after the first symbol. Now:

  - if ε ∈ FIRST(*A*), then FIRST(α) is FIRST(A) ∪ FIRST(TAIL(α)).
  - otherwise, FIRST(α) is FIRST(*A*).

Now, how do we compute FIRST(*A*), for every non-terminal *A*? Using the above definition of FIRST(α), we recursively define FIRST(*A*) to be the union of the sets FIRST(α) for every α which is the right-hand side of a production *A* → α.

The FOLLOW function defines the set of terminal symbols which might appear after the expansion of a non-terminal. It is only defined on non-terminals; if you look carefully at the LL(1) conditions on the page you cite, you'll see that FIRST is applied to a right-hand side, while FOLLOW is only applied to left-hand sides.